# How to change the cell color of a cell of an R Shiny data table dependent on it's value?

Tags: r, html-table, shiny

I am attempting to change the cell color of cells of an R Shiny data table dependent on their value. As an example, I've created the following app:

```
# ui.R

fluidPage(
  # Outputting data table.
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

# server.R

library(DT)

data(iris)

function(input, output) {

  # Rendering data table.
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    head(iris)
  },
  options = list(dom = "t",
                 ordering = FALSE))

}
```

And the following is the generated HTML skeleton and resultant page from the above code:

[image: HTML code generated by R Shiny to display the first 6 lines of the iris dataset as a data table]

[image: first 6 lines of the iris dataset displayed as a data table in R Shiny]

As an example, lets say that I want all cells containing integers to be colored red. Selectively, I'd like to color only the cells at row 2 column 2 and row 5 column 1 where the values are 3 and 5 respectively. Is this possible in R Shiny?

My current idea for a work around is to set the class of individual cells server-side and color them later with CSS. However, I can't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two ideas:

> I want all cells containing integers to be colored red

(1) Mark integers using Javascript:

```
library(DT)
df <- head(iris)
df %>% 
  datatable %>% 
  formatStyle(1:4, color = JS("value % 1 === 0 ? 'red' : ''"))
```

> Selectively, I'd like to color only the cells at row 2 column 2 and
>   row 5 column 1

(2) Mark cells using hidden value columns:

```
m <- matrix(F, ncol = ncol(df)-1, nrow = nrow(df))
m[rbind(c(2,2),c(5,1))] <- TRUE
df %>% 
  cbind(m) %>% 
  datatable(
    options=list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=1:4+ncol(df)))),
  ) %>% 
  formatStyle(
    columns = 1:4, 
    valueColumns = 1:4+ncol(df), 
    color = styleEqual(c(1,0), c("red", "black"))
  )
```

I'm abstracting from Shiny, since this seems to be a datatable question. Also, there may be better options.

Comment: For the Javascript solution, is it possible to color other cells differently according to a different metric? For instance, what if I also wanted to color all cells with letters green in addition to the previous red coloring?

Comment: @michaelmccarthy404 Sure, for example `df[1,1] <- "a";df %>% datatable %>% formatStyle(1:4, color = JS("value % 1 === 0 ? 'red' : String(value).match(/[A-z]+/) ? 'green' : ''"))`?

Answer (score 7):

This page has a bunch of tips for formatting DT data tables: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html

For your specific question, there's the function `formatStyle` that allows you to set aesthetics based on specific values in the table:

```
library(DT)
options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 5))
df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))

# style V6 based on values of V6
datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(
    'V6',
    backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow'))
)

# style V1 based on values of V6
datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(
    'V1', 'V6',
    backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow'))
)
```